# What is the Best Practice to Resolve SQL Server Statement WHERE Parentheses Not Applying Both Conditions Together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This WHERE clause returns data as if the parentheses were not there.  What is the best practice to return data with either `'wholesale'` or `'restaurant'` but not both?

```
SELECT fruit, price, market
FROM fruit_data
WHERE
   fruit = 'banana'
   AND (vendor != 'wholesale' AND market != 'restaurant')
```

My solution does does not strike me as the best practice, although it works:

```
   AND (
       (vendor != 'wholesale' AND market = 'restaurant')
       OR (vendor = 'wholesale' AND market != 'restaurant')
       OR (vendor != 'wholesale' AND market != 'restaurant')
       )
```

Comment: *"This WHERE clause returns data as if the parentheses were not there."* doubtful, and that's your understanding that wrong. What are you trying to do here? Sample data, and epected results will help us help you.

Comment: Your "solution" appears equivalent to `AND NOT (vendor = 'wholesale' AND market = 'restaurant')` or `AND (vendor != 'wholesale' OR market != 'restaurant')`. Take your pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` clause is the same as

```
fruit = 'banana' AND vendor <> 'wholesale' AND market <> 'restaurant'
```

If you expect a different outcome, your logic is incorrect.  Based on your provided "solution", you're want an `OR` in the parentheses:

```
fruit = 'banana'
AND (
    vendor <> 'wholesale'
    OR market <> 'restaurant' )
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...data with either 'wholesale' or 'restaurant' but not both.

A classical approach:

```
select      fruit, price, market
from        fruit_data
where       fruit = 'banana'
and         (vendor = 'wholesale' or market = 'restaurant')
and         not (vendor = 'wholesale' and market = 'restaurant')
```

A more arithmetical approach:

```
select      fruit, price, market
from        fruit_data
cross apply (select 
                isWs = iif(vendor = 'wholesale', 1, 0),
                isRst = iif(market = 'restaraunt', 1, 0)
            ) ap
where       fruit = 'banana'
and         isWs + isRst = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

> data with either 'wholesale' or 'restaurant' but not both?

Wouldn't this be:

`vendor = 'wholesale' OR  market = 'restaurant' AND(NOT(vendor = 'wholesale' AND market = 'restaurant'))`